# Knockout.js: Changing multiple observables through a loop won't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

what I'm trying to do is pretty simple, I want to update an observable property from a list of objects. This is what I have:

```
// cars is an observablearray, and q is an observable    
for(i=0; i < self.cars().length, i++) {
    self.cars()[i].q(0);
}
```

The code is executed only once. If the current value of q is 0 then it goes to the next (i.e. i=1), but as soon as it changes 1 object it returns. Anybody has an explanation of this behaviour? Is there a "knockout" way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you maybe put together a jsfiddle which demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Could you at least post the code for your two objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use the arrayForEach method for that:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.cars(), function (item)
    {
        item.q(0);
    });
```

Does that work any better for you?

Comment: Worked like a charm Paul. I guess that's the Knockout way, thanks!